# Error when Importing External tex Table

Tags: tables, texstudio

everyone

I'm trying to import an external table into my main tex file, but got the error 'Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence' when I tried to Compile my document.

My `main.tex` looks like this:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[right=1.25in,left=1.25in,top=1.1in,bottom=1.1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 
    \usepackage{engord}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{threeparttable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
    \pgfplotsset{every axis label/.append style={font=\tiny}}
    \usepackage[labelsep=period]{caption} %% This switches "Table 1: Title" to "Table 1. Title"
    
    \usepackage{amssymb} %% Necessary, just for the \checkmark command  in tables.
    \usepackage{multirow} %% Necessary if we are doing tables in LaTeX
    \usepackage{xr}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \onehalfspacing        
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \sectionfont{\large}
    \subsectionfont{\normalsize}
    \subsubsectionfont{\normalsize}        
   \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
    
   

\section{Introduction\label{sec:introduction}}
        
        \input{external_table.tex}

    
    \end{document}
```

And my `external_table.tex` looks like

```
\begin{table}[h]
   \centering
   \begin{adjustbox}{width = \textwidth, center}
      \begin{threeparttable}[b]
         \caption{\label{IV_wage_1} Title  (Dep. Var: y)}
         \bigskip
         \begin{tabular}{lccc}
            \toprule
                                                      & Educação1     & Educação2  & Educação3 \\   
                                                      & (1)              & (2)             & (3)\\  
            \midrule 
            X                                       & 0.379$^{*}$      & 0.639$^{**}$    & 0.320\\   
                                                      & (0.193)          & (0.296)         & (0.201)\\   
            1o Estágio                                & -0.097***(0.026) & -0.09***(0.026) & -0.094***(0.026)\\  
             \\
            Observations                              & 231              & 215             & 231\\  
            F-test (1st stage) & 12.7             & 9.02            & 9.82\\  
             \\
            ano fixed effects                         & $\checkmark$     & $\checkmark$    & $\checkmark$\\   
            UF fixed effects                          & $\checkmark$     & $\checkmark$    & $\checkmark$\\   
            \bottomrule
         \end{tabular}
         
      \end{threeparttable}
   \end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
```

Is there any way to avoid this error and import the table directly ?

Comment: Actually not, @Sebastiano. I've already gone through this question but didn't work :/

Comment: Is  the file  external_table.tex  encoded in UTF-8?  If it is encoded in some 8-bit-encoding, e.g. Windows cp1252, or Latin1/Iso-8859-1, you easily get errors about invalid utf-8 bytes with nowadays LaTeX. This is because if the preamble does not load the inputenc  package, nowadays LaTeX by default loads the inputenc-package with utf-8-option before processing the content of the document-environment. In order to guess the encoding of  external_table.tex  one needs to see the exact error-message, inclusive llinebreaks in the error-message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @UlrichDiez. This external table was generated in the statistical software R and the errors presented when I try to load this file into my `main.tex` are all related to Invalid UTF-8 among special characters (i.e 'Educação', 'Estágio', etc). Since I have many different tables like this one to load, I'm trying to find a way to do that without having to edit the preamble of every external table

Comment: So the file was created by R. How did R encode that file? If you know how R encoded that file, then in your document-preamble you can load the package inputenc via `\usepackage{inputenc}` and then do `\inputencoding{<encoding of external_table.tex>} \input{external_table.tex}\inputencoding{utf8}`.

Comment: @ph_9933 it is hard for us to debug as this site is always UTF-8 so your comment `(i.e 'Educação', 'Estágio', etc).` is utf-8 encoded _here_ but your original file is not, it is probably latin1 encoded, your editor should be able to save the file in utf-8